# change the tag in conference booklet

Tags: templates

I am using the template mentioned in https://www.latextemplates.com/template/conference-booklet to create a booklet for a symposium.

In that, they mentioned about the commands \KL, \IS, \CT and \IT commands are used for keynote lectures, invited speakers, contributed talks and invited talks, respectively.

In the symposium I mentioned, I am planning to change the above commands to \F, \PD, \PhD, \IPhD commands for Faculty talk, Postdoc talk, PhD student talk, IPhD student talk. So, in the zip folder that I downloaded, there is a file that has the name conferencebooklet.cls

There I made the changes, replacing \KL, \IS, \CT and \IT with \F, \PD, \PhD, \IPhD respectively. But, even after this change, when I run, I am still getting KL, IS, CT, IT.

Please see the .cls file mentioned below

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Conference Booklet
% Structural Definitions
% Version 1.0 (24/11/2019)
%
% This template originates from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Maxime Lucas (ml.maximelucas@gmail.com) 
% Pau Clusella
% Modifications for LaTeX Templates by Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com)
%
% License:
% GNU General Public License v3.0
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CLASS CONFIGURATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{conferencebooklet}[2019/12/22 LaTeX Templates Conference Booklet Class v1.0]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}} % Pass through any options to the base class
\ProcessOptions\relax % Process given options

\LoadClass{scrbook} % Load the base class

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REQUIRED PACKAGES AND MISC CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2} % Remove all section numbering

\usepackage{multicol} % Allows table cells to span multiple columns
\usepackage{longtable} % Allows the creation of tables that automatically wrap to the next page

\pagestyle{plain} % Use the plain page style for all headers and footers (only a page number)

\usepackage{scrhack} % Fixes compatibility issues between KOMA-Script and other packages

\usepackage{lastpage} % Required to determine the total number of pages

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[
    top=2.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=2.5cm, % Bottom margin
    inner=1.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3cm, % Outer margin
    footskip=1.4cm, % Space from the bottom margin to the baseline of the footer
    headsep=0.8cm, % Space from the top margin to the baseline of the header
    headheight=0.5cm, % Height of the header
    %showframe % Uncomment to show the frames around the margins for debugging purposes
]{geometry}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS & TYPOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage[sfdefault, lf]{carlito} % Use the Carlito family of sans-serif fonts with lining figures

\usepackage{microtype} % Improve typography

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COLOURS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % Required for defining and using custom colours

\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{255, 117, 40}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{164, 168, 172}
\definecolor{mywhite}{RGB}{235, 238, 231}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{52, 115, 116}

\newcommand{\primarycolor}{myblue}
\newcommand{\secondarycolor}{mywhite}

% Table colours
\newcommand{\tbg}{gray} % Event background
\newcommand{\tfg}{white} % Event foreground (text)
\newcommand{\tbc}{gray!25} % Break background

% Talk types colours
\newcommand{\Fcolor}{myblue!65} % Invited speaker
\newcommand{\PhDcolor}{white} % Contributed talk
\newcommand{\KLcolor}{myorange!45} % Keynote lecture
\newcommand{\ITcolor}{yellow!25} % Invited talk

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LINKS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for links

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    %urlcolor=\primarycolor, % Colour for \url and \href links
    %linkcolor=\primarycolor, % Colour for \nameref links
    hidelinks, % Hide the default boxes around links
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE DEFINITIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{array} % Required for manipulating table columns

\newcommand{\tablebreak}[2]{\rowcolor{\tbc} #1 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\bfseries #2} \\ \hline } % Timetable conference break row
\newcommand{\eventtype}[2]{#1 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor{\tbg}\color{\tfg}\bfseries #2} \\ \hline } % Timetable conference event row

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} % Define a new left-aligned (no justification) column type
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} % Define a new centred column type
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} % Define a new right-aligned column type

\newcommand{\F}[4]{#1 & \cellcolor{\Fcolor}IS & {\bfseries#2}\newline #3 & & #4 \\ \hline} % Invited speaker row
\newcommand{\PhD}[4]{#1 & \cellcolor{\PhDcolor}CT & {\bfseries#2}\newline #3 & & #4 \\ \hline} % Contributed talk row
\newcommand{\KL}[4]{#1 & \cellcolor{\KLcolor}KL & {\bfseries#2}\newline #3 & & #4 \\ \hline} % Keynote lecture row
\newcommand{\IT}[4]{#1 & \cellcolor{\ITcolor}IT & {\bfseries#2}\newline #3 & & #4 \\ \hline} % Invited talk row
\newcommand{\tutorial}[4]{#1 & & {\bfseries#2}\newline #3 & & #4 \\ \hline} % Tutorial row

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER STYLING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newdimen\mybarpadding
\mybarpadding=1.5em\relax % Horizontal padding between the coloured bar and chapter name

\RedeclareSectionCommand[% Adjust the spacing around the \chapter command
    afterskip=4em plus 1pt minus 1pt,% Vertical whitespace under chapters
    beforeskip=-1pt, % Vertical whitespace before chapters
    level=0,% Chapters are the top level command
    toclevel=0,% Chapters are the top level command
]{chapter}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\Huge} % Chapter font style

\RedeclareSectionCommand[% Adjust the spacing around the \section command
    afterskip=6pt,% Vertical whitespace under sections
    beforeskip=3pt, % Vertical whitespace before chapters
    level=1,% Sections are the second level command
    toclevel=1,% Sections are the second level command
]{section}

%------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \ifthispageodd{% Odd pages have the coloured bar to the left of the chapter title
        \hfill% Coloured bar fills available width
        \raisebox{-0.2em}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\textcolor{\primarycolor}{\rule{\paperwidth}{1em}}}}% Coloured bar
        \hspace{\mybarpadding}% Padding between the chapter title and colour bar
        \mbox{#3}% Chapter title
    }{% Even pages have the coloured bar to the right of the chapter title
        \mbox{#3}% Chapter title
        \hspace{\mybarpadding}% Padding between the chapter title and colour bar
        \raisebox{-0.2em}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{\primarycolor}{\rule{\paperwidth}{1em}}}}% Coloured bar
    }%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT STYLING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\abstract}[5]{
    \filbreak % Avoid page breaks within abstracts
    
    {\large \bfseries #1} % Title
    
    {\bfseries \itshape #2} \hfill {#3} % Author(s) and abstract type
    
    \textcolor{mygray}{#4} % Affiliation(s)
    
    #5 % Abstract text
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   POSTER STYLING (SHORT)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\poster}[3]{
    \filbreak % Avoid page breaks within abstracts
    
    {\large\bfseries #1}\\ % Title
    \hspace*{0.75cm} #2, \textit{#3} % Author and affiliation
    
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   VERTICAL LINE IN PAGE MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[scale=1, angle=0, opacity=1]{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}

\AddEverypageHook{%
    \ifthenelse{%
        \isodd{\thepage} \AND \thepage>1 \AND \NOT \thepage=\pageref{LastPage} % If odd page but not the first or last page
    }{%
        \backgroundsetup{
            color=\secondarycolor, % Bar colour
            position=current page.south east, % Position of the bar on the page
            nodeanchor=south east, % Anchor location inside the bar
            contents={\rule{10pt}{0.66\paperheight}} % Bar width and height
            }
    }{}
    %
    \ifthenelse{% 
        \NOT \isodd{\thepage} \AND \NOT \thepage=\pageref{LastPage} % If even page but not the last page
    }{%
        \backgroundsetup{
            color=\secondarycolor, % Bar colour
            position=current page.south west, % Position of the bar on the page
            nodeanchor=south west, % Anchor location inside the bar
            contents={\rule{10pt}{0.66\paperheight}} % Bar width and height
            }
    }{}
    %
    \BgMaterial % Output the background set up above
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TALK TYPE CIRCLE DEFINITIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\circlegeneric}[2]{\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}]  \node[circle, inner sep=3pt, minimum size=0.5em, color=black, fill=#1]{\small \bfseries #2};} % Generic definition of a circle with a custom colour and 2 letters in it

\newcommand{\KLtag}{\circlegeneric{\KLcolor}{KL}} % Keynote lecture circle
\newcommand{\Ftag}{\circlegeneric{\Fcolor}{F}} % Invited speaker circle
\newcommand{\PhDtag}{\circlegeneric{\PhDcolor}{PhD}} % Contributed talk circle
\newcommand{\ITtag}{\circlegeneric{\ITcolor}{IT}} % Invited talk circle

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES THAT CLASH AND MUST BE LOADED LAST
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{pdfpages} % Required for including a full-page image for the cover
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not need to change `conferencebooklet.cls`

Define the new commands, the new tags and the new colors.

**(1)** Start your document as

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[
    openany, % Allow chapters to start on odd and even pages
    parskip=full, % Large space between paragraphs
    12pt, % Default font size
    a4paper, % Paper size, use letterpaper for US letter size
]{conferencebooklet} % Custom class defining the style and layout of the template   

%*****************************************************************  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\F}[4]{#1 & \cellcolor{\Fcolor}F & {\bfseries#2}\newline #3 & & #4 \\ \hline} % Faculty talk, row
\newcommand{\PD}[4]{#1 & \cellcolor{\PDcolor}PD & {\bfseries#2}\newline #3 & & #4 \\ \hline} % Postdoc talk row
\newcommand{\PhD}[4]{#1 & \cellcolor{\PhDcolor}PhD & {\bfseries#2}\newline #3 & & #4 \\ \hline} %  PhD  talk row
\newcommand{\IPhD}[4]{#1 & \cellcolor{\IPhDcolor}IPhD & {\bfseries#2}\newline #3 & & #4 \\ \hline} % Student talk row

\newcommand{\Ftag}{\abstractcircle{\Fcolor}{F}} % Faculty lecture circle
\newcommand{\PDtag}{\abstractcircle{\PDcolor}{PD}} % Postdoc speaker circle
\newcommand{\PhDtag}{\abstractcircle{\PhDcolor}{PhD}} % PhD talk circle
\newcommand{\IPhDtag}{\abstractcircle{\IPhDcolor}{IPhD}} % Student talk circle

\newcommand{\abstractcircle}[2]{\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-0.8ex]current bounding box.center)}]
  \node[circle,  minimum size=2.5em,  color=black, fill=#1]{\small \bfseries #2};} % circle for abstracts with a custom colour and 3 letters in it

% Talk types colours
\newcommand{\Fcolor}{blue!35} % Faculty
\newcommand{\PDcolor}{red!40} % PostDoc
\newcommand{\PhDcolor}{orange!35} % PhD
\newcommand{\IPhDcolor}{green!25} % Student
% ***************************************************************************************************************

\begin{document}
```

**(2)** Write the timetable using the new defined commands (the second column was made wider)

```
%    TIMETABLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{Timetable}

PhD: PhD student talk, PD: Postdoc talk, F: Faculty talk,  IPhD: student talk.

\section{Tuesday, 20 of March}

\begin{longtable}{|C{0.15\linewidth}| C{0.07\linewidth}|  C{0.3\linewidth} C{0.0\linewidth} C{0.4\linewidth}|}% changed second column width <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \hline  
    \tablebreak{8:30--9:00}{Registration}
    \tablebreak{9:00--9:10}{Welcome remarks}
    \F{9:10--10:05}{Leon Tremblay}{Montreal, Canada}{Title of a Faculty talk}
    \PhD{10:05--10:30}{Marc Fournier}{Brussels, Belgium}{Title of PhD  talk}
    \tablebreak{10:30--11:00}{Coffee}
    \PD{11:00--11:40}{Hiroya Sato}{Tokyo, Japan}{Title of Postdoc talk}
    \PhD{11:40--12:45}{Marc Smith}{Brussels, Belgium}{Title of PhD  talk with math and paragraphs}
    \tablebreak{12:45--14:00}{Lunch}
    \PhD{14:00--14:30}{Marc Rodriguez}{Barcelona, Spain}{Title of PhD  talk with math and references}
    \PD{14:30--15:05}{Hiroya Sato}{Tokyo, Japan}{Title of Postdoc talk}
    \tablebreak{15:05--15:30}{Coffee}
    \PhD{15:30-16:00}{Marc Jansen}{Amsterdam, The Netherlands}{Title of PhD talk and references and a figure}
    \IPhD{16:00-17:10}{Alberto Dupont}{Madrid, Spain}{Title of student talk}
    \eventtype{17:10--19:30}{Poster session with Wine \& Cheese}
\end{longtable}

\newpage

%------------------------------------------------
```

**(3)** Use the new tags. They can be: empty, `\Ftag` (Faculty talk), `\PDtag` (Postdoc talk), `\PhDtag` (PhD  talk) or `\IPhDtag` (student talk)

```
\abstract\chapter{List of Abstracts -- Talks}

\section{Tuesday 20th}

\abstract
{Title of a Faculty talk} % Title
{L. Tremblay} % Author(s)
{\Ftag} % Tag, can be: empty, \Ftag (Faculty talk), \PDtag (Postdoc talk), \PhDtag (PhD  talk) or \IPhDtag (student talk)
{McGill University, Montreal, Canada} % Affiliation(s)
{Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
    with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
    posteriori.  } % Abstract text

\abstract
{Title of PhD s talk} % Title
{\underline{M. Fournier}$^{1}$, D. Dupont$^{1,2,3}$} % Author(s)
{\PhDtag} % Tag, can be: empty, \Ftag (Faculty talk), \PDtag (Postdoc talk), \PhDtag (PhD student talk) or \IPhDtag (student talk)
{$^1$ Physics Department, Université Libre de Bruxelles, Brussels, Belgium\\ $^2$ Physics Department, Lancaster University, Lancaster, UK\\ $^3$ CSDC, University of Florence, Florence, Italy} % Affiliation(s)
{Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
    with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
    posteriori.} % Abstract text

\abstract
{Title of Postdoc talk} % Title
{H. Sato} % Author(s)
{\PDtag} % Tag, can be: empty, \Ftag (Faculty talk), \PDtag (Postdoc talk), \PhDtag (PhD student talk) or \IPhDtag (student talk)
{Department of Physics, Tokyo Institute of Technology, Tokyo, Japan} % Affiliation(s)
{Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
    with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
    posteriori. } % Abstract text   
    {Title of PhD talk with math and paragraphs} % Title
    {\underline{M. Smith}$^{1}$, D. Dupont$^{1,2,3}$} % Author(s)
    {} % Tag, can be: empty, \Ftag (Faculty talk), \PDtag (Postdoc talk), \PhDtag (PhD student talk) or \IPhDtag (student talk)
    {$^1$ Physics Department, Université Libre de Bruxelles, Brussels, Belgium\\ $^2$ Physics Department, Lancaster University, Lancaster, UK\\ $^3$ CSDC, University of Florence, Florence, Italy} % Affiliation(s)
    {Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
        with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
        posteriori.} % Abstract text
```

[image: y]
[image: z]

Comment: May thanks. this is exactly what I wanted :)